# Angular SSR style (primeng) not loading since Angular 14

Tags: angular, primeng, server-side-rendering

I have an issue with Angular and the ServerSide Rendering. I was in Angular 13, and then when I update to Angular 14 it makes me have an issue with style of some components.
The issue is that only style.scss is taken into account but the theme.css and other style like primeng isn't working.

When I try to npm run prerender, the following error appear : "Unable to extract routes from application."

**The styles works perfectly when I run without ssr (npm run start)**

Angular.json :

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "my-app": {
      "i18n": {
        "sourceLocale": "fr-FR"
      },
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        },
        "@schematics/angular:application": {
          "strict": true
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "fp",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/my-app/browser",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "node_modules/tinymce",
                "output": "/tinymce/"
              },
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "node_modules/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer/assets/",
                "output": "/assets/"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "src/theme.css",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
              "node_modules/primeflex/primeflex.min.css",
              "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css"
            ],
            "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
              "includePaths": [
                "src/styles"
              ]
            },
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "my-app:build:production",
              "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.ts"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "my-app:build:development",
              "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.ts"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "my-app:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "node_modules/tinymce",
                "output": "/tinymce/"
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "src/theme.css",
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
              "node_modules/primeflex/primeflex.min.css",
              "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-eslint/builder:lint",
          "options": {
            "lintFilePatterns": [
              "src/**/*.ts",
              "src/**/*.html"
            ]
          }
        },
        "server": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/my-app/server",
            "main": "server.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.server.json",
            "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
              "includePaths": [
                "src/styles"
              ]
            },
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "outputHashing": "media"
            },
            "development": {
              "optimization": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "extractLicenses": false
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve-ssr": {
          "builder": "@nguniversal/builders:ssr-dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "my-app:build:development",
              "serverTarget": "my-app:server:development"
            },
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "my-app:build:production",
              "serverTarget": "my-app:server:production"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "prerender": {
          "builder": "@nguniversal/builders:prerender",
          "options": {
            "routes": [
              "/"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget":my-app:build:production",
              "serverTarget": "my-app:server:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "my-app:build:development",
              "serverTarget": "my-app:server:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "schematicCollections": [
      "@angular-eslint/schematics"
    ]
  }
}
```

Package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^14.2.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "^14.2.2",
    "@angular/common": "^14.2.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.2.2",
    "@angular/core": "^14.2.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.2.2",
    "@angular/router": "^14.2.2",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.10.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.1.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.0.0",
    "@nguniversal/builders": "^14.2.3",
    "@nguniversal/common": "^14.2.3",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^14.2.3",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^14.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "@tinymce/tinymce-angular": "^7.0.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "karma-viewport": "^1.0.9",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "ngx-colors": "3.1.4",
    "ngx-extended-pdf-viewer": "^15.0.5",
    "primeflex": "^3.1.3",
    "primeng": "^14.1.2",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "serializr": "^2.0.5",
    "tinymce": "^6.0.2",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
```

server.ts

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';

const domino = require('domino');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const templateA = fs
  .readFileSync(path.join('dist/my-app/browser', 'index.html'))
  .toString();
const win = domino.createWindow(templateA);
win.Object = Object;
win.Math = Math;

global['window'] = win;
global['document'] = win.document;
global['navigator'] = win.navigator;

import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
import * as express from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';

import { AppServerModule } from './src/main.server';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { existsSync } from 'fs';

// The Express app is exported so that it can be used by serverless Functions.
export function app(): express.Express {
  const server = express();
  const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/my-app/browser');
  const indexHtml = existsSync(join(distFolder, 'index.original.html')) ? 'index.original.html' : 'index';

  // Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/express-engine)
  server.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModule
  }));

  server.set('view engine', 'html');
  server.set('views', distFolder);

  // Example Express Rest API endpoints
  // server.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
  // Serve static files from /browser
  server.get('*.*', express.static(distFolder, {
    maxAge: '1y'
  }));

  // All regular routes use the Universal engine
  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render(indexHtml, { req, providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }] });
  });

  return server;
}

function run(): void {
  const port = process.env['PORT'] || 4200;

  // Start up the Node server
  const server = app();
  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
}

// Webpack will replace 'require' with '__webpack_require__'
// '__non_webpack_require__' is a proxy to Node 'require'
// The below code is to ensure that the server is run only when not requiring the bundle.
declare const __non_webpack_require__: NodeRequire;
const mainModule = __non_webpack_require__.main;
const moduleFilename = mainModule && mainModule.filename || '';
if (moduleFilename === __filename || moduleFilename.includes('iisnode')) {
  run();
}

export * from './src/main.server';
```

I tried to remove SSR (because it was from the Angular 13) and reinstall it.
I tried to change some options in the angular.json.
I really don't know where the error come from...

If anyone have an idea from where I can fix the issue, it'll help me a lot. Thanks for reading.

**EDIT / SOLUTION :**

A solution that works for me was :

Adding 'CommonJS' as module from tsconfig.server.ts
`"compilerOptions": { ... 'module': 'CommonJS'}`

Adding the inlineCriticalCss to false in the engine of the server :

```
  server.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModule,
    inlineCriticalCss: false,
  }));
```

And then adding the optimization part inside the angular.json in the "build":"configurations":"production":

```
"optimization": {
  "scripts": true,
  "styles": {
    "minify": true,
    "inlineCritical": false
  },
  "fonts": false
 }
},
```

Comment: You didn't add the styles to the `"architect:build:server"` section

Comment: Did you mean in the server part of angular.json I need to add like "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css" in the stylePreprocessorOptions ? @Pieterjan

Comment: Yup exactlypppi

Comment: It seems to not work for me, I add this :

"stylePreprocessorOptions": {
        "includePaths": [
                "src/styles.scss",
                "src/assets/style.css",
                "src/theme.css",
                "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
                "node_modules/primeflex/primeflex.min.css",
                "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css"
         ]
}, 
But the primeflex's classes doesn't work

Comment: No, not there, in the [server](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MintPlayer.Web/ClientApp/angular.json#L145) part, [like so](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MintPlayer.Web/ClientApp/angular.json#L148) However I see that in my case it's not there either, so it must be something else

Comment: Error with the schema if I want to add "styles". And it's in the server:stylePreprocessorOptions where I put this. If you have any idea where I can search

Comment: A solution that works for me was :

Adding 'CommonJS' as module from tsconfig.server.ts
`"compilerOptions": { ... 'module': 'CommonJS'}`

Adding the inlineCriticalCss to false in the engine of the server : 

```
  server.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModule,
    inlineCriticalCss: false,
  }));
```

And then adding the optimization part inside the angular.json in the "build":"configurations":"production":

```
"optimization": {
  "scripts": true,
  "styles": {
    "minify": true,
    "inlineCritical": false
  },
  "fonts": false
 }
},
```

Comment: I had similar issue, the best option that worked for me was using prerender